# How to make range based on first letter of user input?

Tags: python-3.x

How do I return something based on the first letter of user input?

```
def which_day(last_name):
    if (last_name[0]) == "A" or "H":
        return "You should attend lecture in person on Monday"
```

last_name = input("Enter your last name: ")
which_day(last_name)

Comment: Try `last_name[0] in ["A", "H"]`

Comment: no didn't work :/

Comment: If it did not work then we need more to go on. Can you give an example of a `last_name` that starts with a capital `A` and what result you do get when you try say `print(which_day("Andrew"))`?

Comment: I type in Apples as my last name for the input and then nothing else returns no matter what ive tried so far

Comment: Add an `else:` to the if and print `last_name[0]`

Comment: I got it to work, for some reason the return wasn't returning anything so I changed it to print and everything works , thank you for the help

Answer (score 2):

Your if statement will be True regardless of the user input, because the `or "H"` part returns `True` all the time because "H" is not `None`.

To make it work you should rewrite your code to look more like the following:

```
def which_day(last_name):
    if last_name[0] == "A" or last_name[0] == "H":
        return "You should attend lecture in person on Monday"
```

JonSG's suggestions should work too though and would look like this in your code sample

```
def which_day(last_name):
    if last_name[0] in ["A","H"]:
        return "You should attend lecture in person on Monday"
```

You can add more letters to the list if you want to include them to be true. If you also want to trigger the conditional if the name is lowercase turn `last_name[0]` to `last_name[0].upper()`

Comment: It is nice that you point out "why" the existing code might not be working, not just providing a fix.

Comment: What error do you get? Is the name maybe lowercase?

Comment: Are the names you are supplying starting with a space or are lowercase letter